# the type or namespace name luisresult could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have a C# chatbot and I want to connect LUIS API to it but I keep getting this error:
the type or namespace name luisresult could not be found
how can I solve this error?

```
 private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        switch (intent)
        {
            case "Approval":
            
                await ProcessCovid19LuisAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                break;
            // case "l_Weather":
            //     await ProcessWeatherAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
            //     break;
            
            default:
                _logger.LogInformation($"Covid19Bot unrecognized you.");
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Covid19Bot unrecognized you, kindly type a question as what is the symptoms of covid19."), cancellationToken);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Press Ctrl + .  to get the suggestions on the error line Are you prompted to install something?

Answer (score 0):

The message you're getting is that the `LuisResult` type you're using could not be found.

If you're working with Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3, there is a [`LuisResult` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.luis.models.luisresult?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0) in the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models` namespace.

Since you're working with a [`RecognizerResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.recognizerresult), chances are you're working with Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4. In that case, you cannot use V3 types for the information in a V4 result.